# Is it possible to insert checkbox and text(value) to a same wxGrid cell??Or can i insert more than one checkbox to a single wxGrid cell?

Tags: checkbox, cell, wxwidgets, wxgrid

I was creating a table using wxGrid and i need to insert two or three checkbox to a single wxGrid cell.How to create multiple checkbox inside a cell??
Or may i be able to create wxGrid inside a wxGrid cell??

Comment: You might also use `GetGridWindow ()` and manually draw on the grid; however, you need to calculate/control coordinates manually.

Answer (score 3):

Each cell has an [editor](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_cell_editor.html) and a [renderer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_cell_renderer.html). They can be the deafult ones or you can set them.

This makes no possible to add more than one object to a cell.

How would it be otherwise? How to tell the editor/rendered to be used?

What you can do is set the editor/renderer whenever you like, this is, in response to some event.

Any how, I don't think a control that changes its nature is something user-friendly.

Theoretically, a wxGrid inside a cell may be possible. But, again, I don't think it's a good design.

Comment: @Rip2, inserting the check box and text is possible as checkbox control does have a text by default. You can also try to insert a radio box in a cell, but you will have to create an appropriate renderer/editor for that.

Comment: @Igor Yes, but that text is a label, not user-editable like a wxTextCtrl.